# Minimizing distance variance between points on a sphere

Tags: geometry, optimization

If we uniformly distribute N points on a sphere, and must visit each point exactly once in succession such as to form a fully covering path, is there an approach to selecting this order such as to minimize the variance in (path) distance between any given two points? (The path may self-intersect)

Comment: Isn't this the Travelling Salesman Problem as minimizing the mean is the same as minimizing the sum?

Comment: Perhaps the metric is ill-chosen. I'm looking to minimize entropy, maybe you have any ideas on a better one?

Comment: What entropy do you mean?

Comment: If we start at "the top" and traverse down the Y-axis in a swirl pattern, then the distance between a point and its geometrically immediate neighbours would be significantly different depending on whether or not a neighbour is the successor/predecessor on the path. I.e. I'm looking for as tight of a distribution as possible of the distances between all nodes

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand. Do you want to minimize the variance of step lengths? It might - counterintuitively? - be good heuristics to make as long steps as possible (with a lot of zigzag) then